# Mongo query to get comma separated value

Tags: json, mongodb, nested

I have query which is traversing only in forward direction.

example:

```
{
  "orderStatus": "SUBMITTED",
  "orderNumber": "785654",
  "orderLine": [
    {
      "lineNumber": "E1000",
      **"trackingnumber": "12345,67890",**
      "lineStatus": "IN-PROGRESS",
      "lineStatusCode": 50
    }
  ],
  "accountNumber": 9076
}
```

```
find({'orderLine.trackingNumber' : { $regex: "^12345.*"} })**
```

When I use the above query I get the entire document. But I want to fetch the document when I search with **67890** value as well

**At any part of time I will be always querying with single tracking number only.
12345 or 67890** Either with 12345 or 67890. There are chances tracking number value can extend it's value 12345,56789,01234,56678.

I need to pull the whole document no matter what the tracking number is in whatever position.

**OUTPUT**

should be whole document

{
  "orderStatus": "SUBMITTED",
  "orderNumber": "785654",
  "orderLine": [
    {
      "lineNumber": "E1000",
      **"trackingnumber": "12345,67890",**
      "lineStatus": "IN-PROGRESS",
      "lineStatusCode": 50
    }
  ],
  "accountNumber": 9076
}

Also I have done indexing for trackingNumber field. Need help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add the required output and on what condition should the document be returned?

Comment: You mean like `$or`?  Fetch where tracking number is 12345 or 67890?

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit - I should get the whole document as a response. When I query based on tracking number (I querying only one tracking number at a time. It's either 12345 or 67890). I should get the document as a response.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti -  I will be querying based on 1 tracking number at a time. So $or will not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will search with either 12345 or 67890. It is similar to like condition

```
find({'orderLine.trackingNumber' : { $regex: /12345/} })
find({'orderLine.trackingNumber' : { $regex: /67890/} })
```

There's also an alternative way to do this

Create a text index

```
db.order.createIndex({'orderLine.trackingnumber':"text"})
```

You can make use of this index to search the value from trackingnumber field

```
db.order.find({$text:{$search:'12345'}})
--
db.order.find({$text:{$search:'67890'}})
--
//Do take note that you can't search using few in between characters
//like the following query won't give any result..
db.order.find({$text:{$search:'6789'}}) //have purposefully removed 0
```

To further understand how `$text` searches work, please go through the following [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Comment: Thanks Abishek. Unfortunately, this query is not helping me. I'm not getting the result. It's giving me time out. Also. i'm not gonna use or condition. At any given time, I'l be querying based on one tracking number only

Comment: @Arun, by using the first solution `find({'orderLine.trackingNumber' : { $regex: /67890/} })` you will already get the whole document. Or, do you mean to say you only need to get that subdocument in the array based on the trackingNumber filter?

With regards to timeout, you can consider text indexes `db.orders.createIndex( { ''orderLine.trackingNumber" : "text" } )` and make query adjustments based on that.

Comment: Abishek - I have created the index. Still, I'm getting timeout